# Cassandra Error - Clustering column cannot be restricted (preceding column is restricted by a non-EQ relation)

Tags: cassandra, cql, cql3

We are using Cassandra as the data historian for our fleet management solution. We have a table in Cassandra , which stores the details of journey made by the vehicle. The table structure is as given below

```
CREATE TABLE  journeydetails(
bucketid text,
vehicleid text,
starttime timestamp,
stoptime timestamp,
travelduration bigint,
PRIMARY KEY (bucketid,vehicleid,starttime,travelduration)
);
```

Where:

1. bucketid :- partition key which is a combination of month and year
2. vehicleid : -unique id of the vehicle
3. starttime :- start time of the journey
4. endtime :- endtime of  the journey
5. travelduration:- duration of travel in milliseconds

We would like to run the following query - **get all the travels of a vehicle - 1234567 between 2015-12-1 and 2015-12-3 whose travel duration is greater than 30 minutes**

When I run this query:

```
select * from  journeydetails where bucketid in('2015-12') and vehicleid in('1234567') 
  and starttime > '2015-12-1 00:00:00' and starttime < '2015-12-3 23:59:59' 
  and travelduration > 1800000;
```

I get this result:

```
InvalidRequest: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Clustering column "travelduration"
cannot be restricted (preceding column "starttime" is restricted by a non-EQ relation)
```

Does anyone have a recommendation on how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

```
select * from journeydetails where bucketid in('2015-12') and vehicleid in('1234567')
  and starttime > '2015-12-1 00:00:00' and starttime < '2015-12-3 23:59:59' 
  and travelduration > 1800000;
```

That's not going to work.  The reason goes back to how Cassandra stores data on-disk.  The idea with Cassandra is that it is very efficient at returning a single row with a precise key, or at returning a continuous range of rows from the disk.

Your rows are partitioned by `bucketid`, and then sorted on disk by `vehicleid`, `starttime`, and `travelduration`.  Because you are already executing a range query (non-EQ relation) on `starttime`, you cannot restrict the key that follows.  This is because the `travelduration` restriction may disqualify some of the rows in your range condition.  This would result in an inefficient, non-continuous read.  Cassandra is designed to protect you from writing queries (such as this), which may have unpredictable performance.

Here are two alternatives:

1- If you could restrict all of your key columns prior to `travelduration` (with an equals relation), then you could apply a your greater-than condition:

```
select * from journeydetails where bucketid='2015-12' and vehicleid='1234567'
  and starttime='2015-12-1 00:00:00' and travelduration > 1800000;
```

Of course, restricting on an exact `starttime` may not be terribly useful.

2- Another approach would be to omit `travelduration` altogether, and then your original query would work.

```
select * from journeydetails where bucketid='2015-12' and vehicleid='1234567'
  and starttime > '2015-12-1 00:00:00' and starttime < '2015-12-3 23:59:59';
```

Unfortunately, Cassandra does not offer a large degree of query flexibility.  Many people have found success using a solution like [Spark](http://spark.apache.org) (alongside Cassandra) to achieve this level of reporting.

And just a side note, but don't use `IN` unless you have to.  Querying with `IN` is similar to using a secondary index, in that Cassandra has to talk to several nodes to satisfy your query.  Calling it with a single item probably isn't too big of a deal.  But `IN` is one of those old RDBMS habits that you should really break before getting too deep into Cassandra.

Comment: Thanks for the comments Aron... I will explore Spark as an alternative

Answer (score -4):

turns out you can just use 'allow filtering' at the end of the query

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. How does this relate to the question? Please provide more details.

Answer (score -6):

I run into same problem. Instead of playing with the clustered and primary keys, you could simply add an index to the needed columns. With this, you get rid of these pitfalls and you can use whatever column you want in your query.